# Where can I see the default Android styles for things?

Tags: android, xml

I want to modify things like default resources (or at least copy them and add my own modifications), for example `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` -- how would I view the XML for this so I can copy it / modify it in my own default XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml

all of them can be found here:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res

or control-click (or cmd-click if you are on on mac) on `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` in Android Studio.